# Descargar BLOB pdf en iOS con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, blob

Tengo una función que recibe un BLOB desde Ajax, lo que hace esta función es que genera un archivo .PDF para su descarga.

El problema es que en iOS el navegador (Safari) no tiene acceso al gestor de ficheros, y no tengo manera de guardar el archivo como en Windows o en Android que descarga en una ruta en específica, me temo que para iOS tendré que visualizar el PDF desde una ruta en específica. Estoy un poco liado. ¿Cómo podría solicitarlo?

Gracias

```
function descargar(response, status, xhr, nombre){
        var filename = 'CV_'+nombre+'.pdf';                  
        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');

        if (disposition) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches !== null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        } 
            var linkelem = document.createElement('a');
            try {
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });                        
                if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                    //   IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                } 
                else{
                    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    if (filename) { 
                        // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                        // safari doesn't support this yet
                        if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                            window.location = downloadUrl;
                        } else {
                            a.href = downloadUrl;
                            a.download = filename;
                            document.body.appendChild(a);
                            a.target = "_blank";
                            a.click();
                        }
                    } else{
                        window.location = downloadUrl;
                    }
                }   

            } catch (ex) {
                //console.log(ex);
            }
}
```

Comment: Seria absurdo que ios no tuviera gestor de ficheros, estoy seguro que lo tiene, de todas maneras creo que el problema no es como tal el gestor de ficheros, si no safari, ya que supongo estas usando el explorador por defecto de ios.

Comment: @Riven si exacto a eso me refería, el navegador no permite acceder al gestor de ficheros para almacenar el archivo. Me expresé mal, ahora lo actualizo.

Comment: Nisiquiera con el atributo download?, entonces como hace ios para descargar imagenes?, no se no tiene mucho sentido xd, pero te creo, ya que no es de extrañar que ios y su navegador tengan muchos problemas, pues safari es bastante peculiar como navegador movil.

Comment: quiza el problema repercute en la seguridad, es decir, algo que si he notado es que ios se preocupa mucho por la seguridad, y quiza el hecho de que no te deje descargar ese `PDF`, es tal vez porque su descarga es sospechosamente insegura, uno de los casos en los que uno puede detectar esto es que quiza el archivo no tenga un tipo `MIME` asociado o el formato para ese archivo sea invalido, por lo tanto no deja descargarlo, cuando un archivo no tiene tipo `MIME`, se le asigna como tipo generico `application/octet-stream`, que no es mas que formato binario.

Comment: Si tiene tipo mime, ya revisé y ese no es el inconveniente. :/ Gracias

Comment: Que tal si en lugar de poner como tipo `MIME` application/octet-stream, pones el tipo MIME de un PDF?, el cual no recuerdo como es, me parece que era `application/pdf`.

Comment: Si ya lo corregí en mi código y tampoco tiene ganas :(

Comment: de hecho no, tu `Blob` esta constituido como `application/octet-stream`, tu mismo lo especificaste asi al crear el `Blob`.

Comment: Me refiero a que ya lo testee en mi código en el que estoy desarrollando y el inconveniente no se resolvió.

Comment: Ummmm... cuando tu le das click al link que te deberia descargar el `PDF` te aparece algun error?, la verdad no se como se hace inspect desde safari, porque yo no tengo un ios, pero se que se puede hacer inspect, si puedes hacer un inspect para ver si depronto te arroja algun error seria de mucha ayuda, de todas maneras es raro que nisiquiera te aparezca el mensaje de que se esta descargando un archivo.

Comment: Buscaré otra solución, ya encontré una documentación en donde efectivamente iOS no tiene sistema de archivos y esto que estoy haciendo es imposible, lo que tengo que hacer es después de obtener el blob, mostrar una url nueva con el pdf generado. Gracias por el interés. Saludos.

Comment: Una pregunta mas... necesito unos cuantos detalles mas, por ejemplo, que ocurre al  intentar abrir el link?, no ocurre nada?, se cierra el navegador?, notas algo extraño al hacerlo?, se abre una pagina externa pero no se descarga nada?, que ocurre?

Comment: si no tiene sistema de archivos como descargas imagenes o videos desde alguna pagina web? :c

Comment: No lo sé, pero ya vi que no soy el único con el problema. Con respecto al tema, simplemente no hace nada, no hay errores no hay nada, sin embargo, con ese mismo código en windows y Android se inicializa la descarga automáticamente y se descarga el archivo en la carpeta por default (android) en windows abre la ventana para que selecciones en donde guardarla.

Comment: prueba a descargar un recurso cualquiera desde un link, si funciona entonces hay alguna peculiaridad en el navegador o en el codigo que hace que funcione diferente para safari IOS, dudo mucho que el problema sea el sistema de archivos, ya que si esto es cierto entonces IOS es una estafa bastante seria, es decir, como no le ponen un sistema de archivos a su sistema?, la verdad seria algo terrible por parte de ios.